# how to send all the data of array list to another activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-bundle, android-parser

```
Daily Screen :-

public class DailyScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ImageView add, edit;
    MyCustomAdapter adapter1;
    Button ok;
    Button next2;

    final Context context = this;
    ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    List<Milk> items=new ArrayList();

    public List<Milk> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Milk> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.daily_listview);


        add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add);
        edit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        next2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next2);

        Milk milkDefault=new Milk("Toned Milk",0);
        items.add(milkDefault);
        //this.setArrayList((ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter1 = new MyCustomAdapter(items, this);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);// to set context menu in list view
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        next2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DailyScreen.this, SupplierActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("LIST_ITEMS",List,items);//

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DailyScreen.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Enter new Milk");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_box);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                dialog.show();

                final EditText editText = (EditText)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.pro);
                String data = editText.getText().toString();
                //button initialization
                Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String data = editText.getText().toString();
                        if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                            items.add(new Milk(data,0));
                            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product name is :" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(DailyScreen.this, "Please enter the data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }

        });
    }
```

MyCustomAdapter class

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private List<Milk> list = new ArrayList<Milk>();
    private Context context;

    public MyCustomAdapter(List<Milk> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        }
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        name.setText(list.get(position).getNsme());
        final TextView milkCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.milkcount);
        milkCount.setText(""+list.get(position).getAmount());
        ImageView increment = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        ImageView decrement = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_item);
        increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(milkCount.getText().toString().trim());
                a = a + 1;
                milkCount.setText("" + a);
                list.get(position).setAmount(a);
            }
        });
        decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(milkCount.getText().toString().trim());
                if (a == 0) {
                    a = 0;
                } else {
                    a = a - 1;
                }
                milkCount.setText("" + a);
                list.get(position).setAmount(a);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Milk class

```
public class Milk {

    private String nsme ;
    private int amount ;

    public Milk(String nsme, int amount) {
        this.nsme = nsme;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getNsme() {
        return nsme;
    }

    public void setNsme(String nsme) {
        this.nsme = nsme;
    }
    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
```

> i have tried all thing  to send all the data of list view to another activty please suggest me how can i do it ??

Comment: Try this: Keep the arrayList in a utility/single instance
 class and use it.

Comment: Holy wall of code Batman!

Comment: i have tried that one @Raghavendra

Comment: @jyotiswain how you have tried? can u post that code?

Comment: @Raghavendra i have deleted  the code but i have used bundle to do that

Comment: @jyotiswain okay.. What I'm saying is create a single instance class(Don't extend bundle in this case) and keep a hashmap in it and use set method with a key to store this arraylist in activity1 and use the same key to get the arraylist in activity2. I'm not sure performance wise its optimised soln. or not. If u r still not getting what I'm saying I'll try to post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. May be it help.

Send arraylist to activity through extras.

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("ARRAY_LIST", arrayList);
```

Retrieve arraylist in activity.

```
arrayList= i.getStringArrayListExtra("ARRAY_LIST");
```

If u have to send arraylist other than string then.

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("ARRAY_LIST", (ArrayList<Milk>) milkArrayList);
```

Milk class must be parcellable

Comment: I think arrayList of type Milk required

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DailyScreen.this, SupplierActivity.class);
              //  by using permitive
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("ARRAY_LIST",  items);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Make the list static and u can then access it in any activity. Make sure u initialise the list

Answer (score 0):

```
milk class extends serializable firstly
then u do
make object of milk class in mainactivity class
Milk milk=new Milk(this);
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Update.class);
            i.putExtra("emnumber",(Serializable)milk);
            startActivity(i);
then u can pick the value in update class
if(getIntent().getSerializableExtra("emnumber")!=null) {
            con = (ArrayList<Contact>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("emnumber");
            email_mobile = contactList.get(0).nsme;
            pass__word = contactList.get(0).amount;
```

Comment: u use activity class for receive intent data firstly

Comment: List<Milk> con=new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

you can implement as:

```
    public class Milk implements Parcelable{
```

......
}

Send arraylist as:

```
    intent.putExtra("files", "your arraylist");
```

obtain arraylist as:

```
     Intent inIntent = getIntent();
    list=inIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("files");
```